# БД Oracle съедает ОЗУ

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, windows-server-2012

При перезагрузке или включениии сервера, всё работает идеально, память в норме, колличество сессий тоже. Но спустя 2-3 дня непрерывной работы повышается потребляемая память причем значительно и увеличеваются колличество сессий до 450+. Насколько я знаю сессии БД должна выкидывать сама и проблем с этим не должно быть.

Но что происходит с памятью? На данный момент это 5.4гб, прошло 3 дня. Завтра будет еще больше. В конце упрётся в то что база перестанет принимать новые соединения даже если всё выгрузить. Помогает только перезагрузка.

Помогите разобраться.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Дополнено**

Если грешить на не правильное распределение памяти PGA\SGA, давайте посмотрим, что есть по факту, не силён в администрировании:

```
SELECT name, sum(value/1024) "Value - KB"
   FROM v$statname n,
        v$session s,
        v$sesstat t
  WHERE s.sid=t.sid
    AND n.statistic# = t.statistic#
    AND s.type = 'USER'
    AND s.username is not NULL
    AND n.name in ('session pga memory', 'session pga memory max', 
        'session uga memory', 'session uga memory max')
  GROUP BY name
```

На выходе получаем:

> session uga memory 24672,609375
>
> session uga memory max 66495,8515625
>
> session pga memory 46984
>
> session pga memory max 237577,875

Посмотрим на SGA:

```
SELECT (
   (SELECT SUM(value) FROM V$SGA) -
   (SELECT CURRENT_SIZE FROM V$SGA_DYNAMIC_FREE_MEMORY)
   ) "SGA_TARGET"
FROM DUAL;
```

Вывод:

> SGA_TARGET: 5465165824

---

PS ОС Windows Server, 2012 DB Oracle 11g-r2

Comment: БД сама сессии выкидывать не будет, пока не разорвется tcp соединение которое обеспечивает эту сессию. Так что я бы начал с изучения приложения, пользующегося БД на предмет забывания открытых сессий

Comment: @Mike Пользователей не так уж и много. Есть приложение IDB компании Siemens вот она плодит сессии вне себя. У неё 1 пулл данных это одна сессия, а всего пулов 15. Работает по принципу открыла, записала, закрыла и так по кругу. Отказаться от данного ПО нет возможности из-за производственной необходимости. Какие можно принять меры борьбы ?

Comment: Есть параметр ресурсов IDLE_TIME, то с ним все не очень просто. вот например что обсуждают http://www.sql.ru/forum/391693/ob-ispolzovanii-idle-time

Comment: Открыла-записала-закрыла не должно приводить к такому эффекту. что то сессию явно не закрывает. надо бы посмотреть что это вообще за сессии через v$session

Comment: @Mike На данный момент нечего показать по сессиям всего 57. Есть некие вопросы к самописному ПО которое весит как INACTIVE всё остальное впорядке на сегодняшний день.

Comment: @Mike Может действительно проблема с неправильным распределением памяти ?

Comment: @Mike Дополнил свой вопрос.

Comment: Непонятно, каков вопрос? Вы дали для SGA 5,4 GB, база с ними и работает. Что вас не устраивает?

Comment: @0xdb Я могу без последствий уменьшить выделение памяти SGA ?

Comment: Ну да, будет помедленней немного, если памяти не будет хватать, БД пишет в во временный tablespace. Поставте 50% от размера физической.

Comment: @0xdb Мне достаточно этих команд ```SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET MEMORY_MAX_TARGET=1200M SCOPE=SPFILE;
SQL> ALTER SYSTEM SET MEMORY_TARGET=2000M SCOPE=SPFILE;``` затем перезапуск экземпляра БД.Или нужно что-то еще ? Если да, оформите пожалуйста как ответ и я закрою тему. Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

О причине коротко: БД выделено слишком много памяти.

Если подробней, следуя [комменатрию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946075/%d0%91%d0%94-oracle-%d1%81%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%9e%d0%97%d0%a3#comment1575168_946140):

> Ранее на это особо вниманиее не обращали пока не вылетела 1 планка памяти, ожидая поставок новой, нужно поддерживать работоспособность сервера

Выделяемая БД память увеличилась с разумной величины (рекомендуемая "золотая середина" 40% физической) до примерно от 80% до 100%.

Необходимо уменьшить размер выделяемой БД памяти (для справки [см. оф.док.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/memory.htm#BGBCBHEJ)).

Посмотреть сколько сейчас выделено:

```
SQL> show parameters _target

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
memory_max_target                    big integer 1G
memory_target                        big integer 1G
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 0
sga_target                           big integer 0
```

Два верхних параметра установлены на текущее значение выделенной памяти. Значение 0 для двух других значит, что включено автоматическое управление памятью (AMM Automatic Memory Management).

Предварительно можно посмотреть, что даст уменьшение выделенной памяти:

```
SQL> select * from v$memory_target_advice order by memory_size;

MEMORY_SIZE MEMORY_SIZE_FACTOR ESTD_DB_TIME ESTD_DB_TIME_FACTOR    VERSION
----------- ------------------ ------------ ------------------- ----------
        256                ,25           17                   1          0
        512                 ,5           17                   1          0
        768                ,75           17                   1          0
       1024                  1           17                   1          0
       1280               1,25           17                   1          0
       1536                1,5           17                   1          0
       1792               1,75           17                   1          0
       2048                  2           17                   1          0
```

Значение `MEMORY_SIZE_FACTOR=1` - текущий фактор размера памяти (1024МБ). В столбце `ESTD_DB_TIME_FACTOR` покажет, ожидаемое изменние производительности БД при изменении размера выделенной памяти от 25% до 2х текущего (на рабочей БД будут другие значения, отличные от 1).

Предположим, надо уменьшить вдвое (512МБ, в вопросе до ~3ГБ):

```
SQL> alter system set memory_max_target=512M scope=spfile;

System altered.

SQL> alter system set memory_target=512M scope=spfile;

System altered.

SQL> shutdown immediate
[...]
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  535662592 bytes
Fixed Size                  1337720 bytes
Variable Size             306185864 bytes
Database Buffers          222298112 bytes
Redo Buffers                5840896 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> show parameters _target

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
memory_max_target                    big integer 512M
memory_target                        big integer 512M
pga_aggregate_target                 big integer 0
sga_target                           big integer 0
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам что спустя время вернулись к старой теме и дали развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: "Рад был помочь" уже как-то не кстати, хотя три года, думаю, в комментариях помог :)

Answer (score 0):

Причин вашей беды может быть множество. Начиная от самого приложения- оракл кэширует запросы, до не правильного распределения размеров SGA, PGA, журналов. При запуске сколько оперативки забирает? Какое управление памятью используете?
Может быть ваше приложение не рассчитано на такой объем ресурсов.
Начните отсюда:
[https://oracle-patches.com/oracle/tuning/3118-настройка-памяти-базы-данных-oracle-буферы,-кэши,-pga](https://oracle-patches.com/oracle/tuning/3118-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-oracle-%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B,-%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8,-pga)

Comment: при запуске потребление памяти стартует от 100мб за выходные выросла до 5+ гб. Ранее на это особо вниманиее не обращали пока не вылетела 1 планка памяти, ожидая поставок новой, нужно поддерживать работоспособность сервера